# DataGridTemplateColumn top margin / padding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, margin, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a StackPanel within my DataGridTemplateColumn. I can't seem to find a way to remove the  margin at the top in this cell.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Description">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,-10" />
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Description1}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Description2}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The margin appears to be from the DataGridTemplateColumn itself rather than the StackPanel since only the first Label has spacing above it.

Answer (score 0):

The margin is actually on your `Labels`, not the `StackPanel`. Simply remove the style for your Labels that is setting the bottom margin to negative, and it will work correctly.

A negative margin seems to get applied after an object has been rendered, and can make a control move out of the existing bounds set for it. In your case, the `Labels` are being rendered, then both are moving down 10px